# SVG icon isn't clickable inside div element

Tags: svg, clickable

SVG icon isn't clickable inside div element. Div is clickable. Here my css:

```
     &__icon { 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.1em;
      right: 50%;
      transform: translateX(50%);
      opacity: 0.5;
      width: 2.5em;
      height: 2.5em;

      svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, based on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925509/13568935

Div is over lapping SVG. Set z-index:-1 to DIV or the SVG element to z-index:2 in css.